# Link variables in matrix tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know if there is an easy way to constrain variables in a matrix in TensorFlow.

As a toy example, I wrote a piece of code where I would like my `input_matrix` to converge towards `[[2., 1.], [1., 2.]]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
v1 = tf.Variable(1.)
v2 = tf.Variable(2.)
#Here I specify that some of the variables in the matrix must have the same values, but it obviously doesn't work since TensorFlow variables need to be initialized before being used
input_matrix = tf.Variable([[v1, v2], [v2, v1]])
objective_matrix = tf.constant([[0., 1.], [1., 4.]])
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-1)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(objective_matrix, input_matrix)))
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cost)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(train_step)
```

Then, is it possible to force some elements of a matrix to be equal or at least the gradients ?

Comment: Constrained optimization no. But you can create an unconstrained variable and specify a transformation which enforces the constraint. So if you just want two elements in a four-element matrix to be equal, you could make an unconstrained variable with three elements and repeat one when defining the matrix (e.g. [a, b, c] -> [a, b, b, c]).

Comment: Smart, thanks for the trick !